# Jenkins windows slave service does not interact with desktop

Tags: service, windows-8, jenkins

I have followed this guide to install a jenkins slave on windows 8 as a service:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-InstallSlaveasaWindowsservice%28require.NET2.0framework%29

I need to run a job that interact with the desktop (run an application that opens a browser etc.). So after I have installed the slave as a service (running jnlp downloaded from the master) I have changed the service "Log on" to "Allow to interact with display".

For some reason its only possible to enable this for the "Local System account" even though its recommended to run the service as a specified user, eg. jenkins.

But nothing happens when I execute the job, the browser is not opened. If I instead stop the service and just launch the slave through the jnlp file the job runs fine - the browser is opened.

Anybody had any luck interacting with the desktop when running a jenkins windows slave as a service?

Comment: *I need to run some jobs that interact with the desktop (opens a browser etc.)* I am pretty sure you can open a browser without it being on *a* desktop.

Comment: Well it works fine when I start the slave through jnlp. But not when its launched as a service. So something is not working the same way when its running as a service.

Comment: You could try moving the component handling the browser out to Selenium which is designed to test the UI of websites http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Services run since Vista in Session 0 and the first user is now in Session 1. So you can't interact any longer. This is called Session 0 Isolation.

Microsoft explains this [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx). You have to use 2nd Program which uses [IPC to communicate to the Service.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Main_IPC_methods)

Answer (score 9):

To resolve it, first create Windows auto-logon as I explain here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/269832/windows-server-2008-automatic-user-logon-on-power-on/606130#606130

Then create a startup batch for Jenkins agent (place it in Jenkins directory). This will launch agent console on desktop, and should allow Jenkins to interact with Windows GUI:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://{Your Jenkins Server}:8080/computer/{Your Jenkins Node}/slave-agent.jnlp
```

(slave.jar can be download from http://{Your Jenkins Server}:8080/jnlpJars/slave.jar)

**EDIT :**
If you're getting **black screenshots** (when using Selenium or Sikuli, for example), create a batch file that disconnects Remote Desktop, instead of closing the RDP session with the regular X button:

```
%windir%\system32\tscon.exe %SESSIONNAME% /dest:console
```

Comment: I disabled my Jenkins service in services.msc and used a similar java command to launch my Jenkins slave through cmd, and that solved the session 0 lockout issue for me.  I found that when you disable the service and then look at your slave node in the Jenkins web UI, it should say "Connection was broken" and show you the exact command to use in cmd at the bottom of the page, as well as a download link for the slave.jar that you need.  That command seems to have a few more arguments that are specific to your setup.

Comment: Same here. I put a simple script into autostart. To get rid of the cmd-window (anoyance, accidental close, ...), use something like hidecon ( http://code.kliu.org/misc/hidecon/ ).

Comment: I don't get the "java" line part. How can you replace the normal remoting.jar start with this command? What do you mean with "you get the slave.jar", can you just download once and that's fine? If you put anything in the Jenkins folder, how is Jenkins gonna look out for it etc.? Many open questions to me

Comment: @IceFire, this is how to run Jenkins **agent** with your own script, instead of using Windows service. So disable the Jenkins service, and call the downloaded jar in your script.

Answer (score 8):

I had lots of issues running Jenkins in Windows using the service.
Instead I now disable the service and run it from CMD.

So open `CMD`.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins

java -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar
jenkins.war --httpPort=9091
```

Comment: This works for me and this should be accepted answer if you asked me. But, OTOH, I really love simple answers. I tried few hours to run Jenkins with desktop interaction enabled in Windows XP Home. Nothing. Worked. Ever. So I just run it from CMD (batch file in StartUp folder) and it works like a breeze. Setting up a service with desktop interaction enabled in WinXP is NOT worth it if you ask me - but, OTOH, I run Jenkins in HyperV VM, so I already have an actual form of "desktop separation" enabled. ALSO, as a bonus, just add your Putty SSH key to StartUp folder and you're set with Mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running the Java slave server directly at startup and then using something to monitor and restart should the server go down (e.g., [Kiwi Restarter](http://www.kiwimonitor.com/kiwi_application_restarter.php)).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the services (@ TestNode) make sure the "Interactive Services Detection" service is STARTED, by default the startup type is set to Manual, you may like to set it to automatic as well.

[image]

After service started, when you run your test in the Test Node, you will see something like the below:
[image]

Click on it and choose view the message

[image]

You will see the activities happen there. Hope this helps :D

***Note: If login with other account and cannot view the Interative Services Detection prompt, restart the service again.***

Comment: Can we interact with real window?

Answer (score 0):

My Jenkins Service runs as user "jenkins" and all I did was to create Desktop folders in: **C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\desktop** and if 64 bit Windows also in **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\desktop** - then it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Desktop` folders are created as such:

- `%WINDOWS%/System32/config/systemprofile/Desktop`
- `%WINDOWS%/SystemWOW64/config/systemprofile/Desktop`

Presence of those can sometimes be mandatory while running some Java software as a Service.