# Python + Selenium + Jenkins on Windows

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

I have multiple UI tests in Python along with Selenium. I am trying to use Jenkins for running these based on builds. The problem is that the tests need to use Firefox browser and cannot be headless in nature. 
They take a long time to run and I have ended up aborting them as no progress or logs are generated.

I have read that on linux this issue can be solved by using the xvfb plugin and running tests. Do we have something similar in Windows with which I can run Firefox browser tests using python and selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can get it [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/installation.html#downloading-python-bindings-for-selenium) and documentation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

Comment: Should you not include some details as well and just not links?

Comment: Not sure what else to say.  If he wants to run selenium tests he can do it with Python, Ruby, Javascript, etc.  on Windows, mac os, etc.  If he just needs to run basic Selenium tests launching a firefox browser (default for selenium) then he should just download the python api (using pip). I have found browerstack.com useful in doing this process, but that seems extraneous to his question.

Comment: thanks but i already have scripts that i run with nose as a test runner. The idea is to run these tests via jenkins. But this seems to be a problem with Windows. On Linux, there is jenkins plugin available called 'xvfb' which allows us to run firefox as browser. I am looking for something similar in windows.

Comment: Are you running your Jenkins as a service in Windows? Services have problems interacting with desktop. Check this [previous answer:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906753/jenkins-windows-slave-service-does-not-interact-with-desktop)

Comment: I'm doing the same thing and I just use browserstack to solve that problem (I know not really solving your problem).  The benefit is that I can run my tests in multiple environments/browsers. Running just in firefox doesn't do anything for me since my app can be used by a host of different browsers/environments.  All of the browser display is on browserstack which you can see live (as it's running). Get a free account and run using some basic config settings to point to them.