# Selenium - Jenkins - CI

Tags: selenium, ant, jenkins

I'm trying to integrate my selenium automation project with Jenkins using ANT build tool.

I've successfully configured a job and I'm able to BUILD too, but my scripts didn't launch the application and perform the test steps as expected. But still I could see the console output as 'BUILD SUCCESS'...!

When I tried to execute the ANT build through command prompt, it got executed appropriately by launching the application and performing required test steps. So expected the same to happen in Jenkins job as well, but it's not happening so.

Please help me in fixing this issue....!

***Note:*** I have followed the steps given in the post below for integrating Jenkins & Selenium-
http://www.ontestautomation.com/running-selenium-webdriver-tests-in-jenkins-using-ant/

Comment: Please give your system information

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of two things

1. Configure Ant: Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Ant installations
2. Invoke Ant: Jenkins > Job > configure > Build > invoke ant targets

Comment: Yes, I made both these setting properly.... but still my job is not launching the application...!?

Answer (score 0):

Followed the steps below to overcome the issue I logged/faced:

1) Upgraded the Chrome to latest version

2) Ensured *'Allow service to interact with deskop'* is checked - refer to the post below for more information:

[Jenkins windows slave service does not interact with desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906753/jenkins-windows-slave-service-does-not-interact-with-desktop][1])

3) Initiated the Jenkins through command prompt **(Jenkins should be stopped in services.msc when we do this)** in traditional way....