# Selenium Timedout Exception while running test cases from Jenkins

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, testng

Am running a set of test cases from Jenkins. All the test cases are failing with `org.openqa.selenium.TimedoutException` on all the functions. I have tested the same code using eclipse in local and its executing fine. Please check on the below error and help on resolving this issue

**Configurations:**

```
Selenium- standalone - jar - 2.53
Chromedriver - 2.36
Chrome Browser - 65
testng jar = 6.8
```

**Code Sample:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(ORCollection.get("BtnMDUEligibilityClick").toString())));
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath(ORCollection.get("BtnMDUEligibilityClick").toString()));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", el);
WebElementClick(" ",ORCollection.get("BtnMDUEligibilityClick").toString());
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

**Logs:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 40 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //button[contains(@class,'js-submit')]
```

I have increased `webdriver.wait` value in code from 40 seconds to 1000 but still we are getting the same error as Timedout.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your XPath expressions are correct and you can manually open the browser on the Jenkins [slave](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) machine.

The issue could be connected with the lack of interactive desktop. This could happen if you have installed Jenkins on the slave machine as windows service. The recommended for Windows way to control a Windows slave is by using **Launch slave agents via Java Web Start**. More info [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906753/jenkins-windows-slave-service-does-not-interact-with-desktop/).